# Ways to create a procedure with optional parameters?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is that possible to create a procedure with optional parameters?
For example, create a procedure that add up all of the parameters.

```
add(n1, n2, .... nn)
```

Another procedure like for example I have 11 parameters, it adds up from 1 to 10, and the last parameter can do something else.
By googling, it seems like you can use array to do it, but most of the results I got was about another programming languages, not plsql. If apply the theory to plsql I guess I suppose to use varray or nested table?

Comment: In PL/SQL the number of parameters for any function or procedure must be fixed at compile time, to allow variable number of parameters you would use an array type instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by `DEFAULT` operator or '='

```
PROCEDURE ADD(NUMBER n1, NUMBER n2, NUMBER n3 DEFAULT 0)....
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#CHDFADII

If you want to use it without explicit parameter naming in calls then you have to place your optional parameters at the end of the procedure signature list. With explicit parameter naming in call they can be placed anywhere

Answer (score 17):

You need to declare parameter with default value:

```
procedure add (n1 number, 
               n2 number default 0,
               ...
               nn number default 99) is ...
```

Using this procedure:

```
begin
  add(1);
  add(5, 6, 7, ..., 111);
  add(n1 => 111, n5 => 345, nn => 17);
end;
```

In last case, as you can see, you can pass values for 3 parameters (`n1`, `n5`, `nn`), for others parameters default values will be used.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you for your reply. Which means I have to type all of the parameters for creating a procedure wtih optional parameters?
Is there another way to do without typing all of the parameters or this is the only way??

Comment: @nicklowkc No other ways. As far as I know, in all other programming languages too. If you need 11 parameters - you have to write 11 parameters in procedure declaration.

Comment: "*in all other programming languages too*" - not really. Other programming languages have "varargs" where you can define a function (or procedure) with a variable number of arguments and then check the actual number inside the function. But PL/SQL does not support this

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, I have never met such languages boefore.

Comment: varargs are just arrays, just that they have easier syntax to use without the need to declare/initialize array objects